# Como faço para utilizar um banco de dados em um site HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho interesse em fazer um site que irá usar banco de dados, muitos me disseram que se usa MySQL para fazer isso, porém não tenho conhecimento sobre ele, instalação, uso etc. Tenho conhecimento em PHP, HTML, CSS e JavaScript, não sei se isso interfere em algo.

Comment: Se você tem conhecimento com PHP, é só seguir as dicas da galera. Se quiser uma ajuda com o uso de BD com o PHP, dá uma olhada: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp Vai te dá uma boa ajuda. []'s

Comment: @PauloViníciusMatos [Não recomende o W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 11):

A pergunta é bastante ampla, mas basicamente você pode usar qualquer banco de dados em um site porque o HTML é uma linguagem de marcação que nada tem a ver com o banco de dados.

Desenvolver Web tem 3 partes básicas:

1. **Servidor HTTP**: É ele que recebe as requisições dos usuários que estão acessando o site, processa as informações e devolve um HTML;
2. **Motor de Processamento**: É chamado pelo servidor para criar um HTML dinamicamente. O PHP é um deles, mas há outros como Python, Ruby, Perl, Scala, Clojure, ASP.NET, Java, etc.
3. **Banco de Dados**: É chamado pelo motor de processamento do seu site para reunir informações que são usadas pelo motor de processamento para processar a página que seu usuário irá ver.

Se você deseja desenvolver em PHP, há vários kits que reúnem servidor HTTP, motor de linguagem e banco de dados. São eles:

- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) (Apache + MySQL + PHP + Perl)
- [LAMP](http://lamphowto.com/) (Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP)
- [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (Windows + Apache + MySQL + PHP)
- [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) (Windows + Apache + MySQL + PHP)

Entretanto, você não precisa usar apenas o Apache como servidor HTTP, nem o PHP como motor de processamento, nem o MySQL como banco de dados. Hoje temos outras alternativas, como por exemplo:

- [Ruby On Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.com.br/) (WEBrick + Ruby + SQLite)
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Django + Python + SQLite)
- [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) (Java ou Scala + H2)
- [ASP.NET MVC5](http://asp.net/mvc) (IIS + C# ou VB.NET + Microsoft SQL Server)

Recomendo fortemente sair do PHP e ir para outra linguagem. Há diversos antigos na Internet que embasam uma série de problemas do PHP, como este do criador do StackOverflow: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html

Comment: Toda e qualquer linguagem possui vantagens e desvantagens. Da mesma forma que existe uma série de problemas com o PHP, também existe no Java, no Python, no Ruby, etc., etc. Sobre o artigo que você postou, você deve ter escapado da conclusão: a linguagem pode não ser um primor em termos de design, mas vai muito bem naquilo em que ela se propõe a resolver.

Comment: Não escapei da conclusão. Apenas sugeri sair do PHP e ir para outra linguagem e embasei com um artigo porque ontem alguém "ficou triste" com o comentário e fez uma edição que não é pertinente. A opinião faz parte da resposta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez muito boa a sua resposta é esse nível que queremos no StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seu conhecimento em PHP seja apenas teórico e bem básico, pois a maioria dos tutoriais na internet tratam o PHP junto com o MySQL. Te aconselho a instalar um pacote como o WAMP, que já foi citado.

Após isso você vai configurar o MySQL e suas tabelas. Use os seguintes links:

- http://protocoloti.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/instalando-e-configuurando-o-mysql-no.html
- http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177460%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Depois comece a desenvolver em PHP. Dentro do arquivo PHP você pode colocar código HTML. Esta é uma boa introdução: http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/introducao-ao-php/

- **Você pode fazer o download do wamp aqui:** http://www.wampserver.com/en/
- **Você tem vários exemplos de código aqui:** http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/forum/59-repositorio-de-scripts-php/ **ou aqui:** http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/tag/php **ou aqui:** http://www.codigofonte.net/scripts/php
- no **Youtube** também tem muitas vídeo-aulas.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL é o recomendado para um website, mas existem outros bancos também.

Instale o [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/%E2%80%8E), ou qualquer outro que tem suporte MySQL, em sua máquina, com ele dá pra ter um servidor localhost, e usar o MySQL;

Pra fazer uma simples conexão php com seu banco:

```
<?php    
//conexão com o servidor
$conect = mysql_connect("endereço_servidor", "usuario_do_banco_de_dados", "senha_banco_de_dados");

// Caso a conexão seja reprovada, exibe na tela uma mensagem de erro
if (!$conect) die ("<h1>Falha na coneco com o Banco de Dados!</h1>");

// Caso a conexão seja aprovada, então conecta o Banco de Dados.    
$db = mysql_select_db("nome_banco_de_dados");

/*Configurando este arquivo, depois é só você dar um include em suas paginas php, isto facilita muito, pois caso haja necessidade de mudar seu Banco de Dados
você altera somente um arquivo*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da sua meta, o [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) é uma plataforma bastante usada, e utiliza o banco de dados. A coisa boa do Wordpress é que o uso do banco de dados está "por trás das cortinhas", ou seja, você não precisa saber como criar tabelas, adivinhar como fazer índices, se preocupar com o tipo de coluna que deve colocar para um campo de nome.

No fundo, o Wordpress usa MySQL, e PHP também, mas salva você de uma boa parte das detalhes técnicas, com muitas plugins e temas para customização.

Answer (score 0):

Deve instalar o Apache, o MySQL e o PHP. Uma maneira de fazer isso é fazer o download do [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)

O próximo passo é a escolha de uma IDE, fica a sua escolha: [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), [phpstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/).

Para possibilitar o debug do PHP é necessário baixar e instalar o XDebug, que nada mais é que uma [DLL](http://xdebug.org/) para acrescentar na configuração do PHP.

para instalar o XDebug faça o seguinte:

Acesse o diretorio de instalação do `php` que vem no xamp, e edite o arquivo `php.ini`.

Ex.: `C:xampp\php\php.ini`

Procure a linha:  `;zend_extension = "C:xamppphpextphp_xdebug.dll"` e descomente ela (tirando o ponto e vírgula), reinicie o seu Apache pronto

[image: botão de refresh]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa instalar um programa que vai fazer de sua máquina um servidor local, no caso eu recomendo

- XAMPP Segundo o próprio site:

> é completamente gratuito e fácil de instalar a distribuição Apache contendo MariaDB

após isso você deve escolher uma ide um exemplo é o

- Eclipse Uma IDE Gratuita e Open source

Para o Banco de Dados é o

- MySql

Após Criar o seu banco e suas tabelas basta fazer a conexão por php

```html
$servername = "NOME DO SERVIDOR";
$username = "NOME DO USUÀRIO";
$password = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME DO BANCO";
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
```